# iPhone X - UIPageControl Black Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have already added the correct size Launch Screen to the project, and the remainder of the app is working correctly, it is only the instances of a UIPageViewController where a black bar appears on only the bottom, not the top, of the screen. What is the solution as I don't know of any attributes that can be modified to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Which version of iOS (there is a bug in same versions)? Which is the bottom constraint? Do you have tried the view debugging inspector?

Comment: @Kerberos iphoneX Simulator 11.4 - There is no bottom constraint - it is simply an instance of UIPageViewController - Regarding the View Hierarchy, The black appears to be from the UINavigationController, but I thought the UIPageViewController should complete cover the screen from top to bottom.

Comment: The only hack that worked was to change the background color of the actual UIPageViewController - but I would assume that is a hack and not supposed to be how it should work. It should stretch to for the full screen.